# Django url change language code

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I am trying to change the language of the website when users click a button in Django.

I have a base project and the urls are:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # Ecommerce is the app where I want to change the language
    url(r'^', include("ecommerce.urls")),
)
```

The url inside Ecommerce.urls is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^testing/$', views.test, name='url_testing'),
    ... other urls
]
```

When I visit the url above, I first go to: `http://localhost/en/testing/`.

I want to set a link `<a href="{% url 'url_testing' %}">Change Language</a>` so that when users click it, it will change language to `http://localhost/zh-hans/testing/`. How do I do this in my template?

**EDIT**

I can now change the language using the following code but the problem is that it only works once:

```
<form id="languageForm" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{% url 'url_testing' %}" /> 
    <input id="newLanguageInput" type="hidden" name="language"/>
</form>
```

And my links are:

```
<li><a onclick="changeLanguage('zh-hans')">简体</a></li>
<li><a onclick="changeLanguage('zh-hant')">繁體</a></li>
```

The function changeLanguage is defined like:

```
function changeLanguage(newLanguage) {
    $('input[name="newLanguageInput"]').val(newLanguage);
    $('#languageForm').submit();
}
```

The code works when I first click any of the 2 links, and I will be redirected to the url `http://localhost/zh-hans/testing/` or `http://localhost/zh-hant/testing/`. The problem is after I change the language once, it no longer changes. Is there something wrong with my submit?

Answer (score 6):

You can change the language of the website when users click a link (no url translation, no post) like this:

*navigation.html (with bootstrap4 and font awesome)*

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

    {% get_available_languages as languages %}
    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}

    <a href="{% url 'main:activate_language' lang_code %}" class="dropdown-item">
      {% if lang_code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% else %}
        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% endif %}
      {{ lang_name }} ({{ lang_code }})
    </a>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</li>
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import translation
from django.views.generic.base import View

class ActivateLanguageView(View):
    language_code = ''
    redirect_to   = ''

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.redirect_to   = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        self.language_code = kwargs.get('language_code')
        translation.activate(self.language_code)
        request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = self.language_code
        return redirect(self.redirect_to)
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ActivateLanguageView

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('language/activate/<language_code>/', ActivateLanguageView.as_view(), name='activate_language'),
]
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's not going to be a simple `<a>` link but a `<form>`.

Have a read on [how to `set_language` redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view). This form will be responsible for changing languages. It's easy as a pie.

Make sure you have set some [`LANGUAGES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#languages) first.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a link and not a form?

Comment: I believe that yes, it can be done **but** you will loose the language setting on the next request. It's not going to be persistent.

Comment: @RgfvfkIff You can make your own view to change languages in a GET request, but the reason this isn't done is that you shouldn't change settings in GET requests, because of CSRF susceptibility. If your users visit another site, that site could change their language.

Answer (score 3):

New snippets compatible with new API (Boostrap 5 and Django >= 4.0) updated from the excellent @Boris Đurkan answer.

Django has dropped the [`translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) support.
So basically we need to make this setup using the session cookie.

```
class ActivateLanguageView(View):

    def get(self, request, lang, **kwargs):
        url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
        translation.activate(lang)
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang)
        return response
```

Boostrap has changed its jQuery binding for dropdown:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <strong>{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}</strong>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

    {% get_available_languages as languages %}
    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}

    <a href="{% url 'activate_language' lang_code %}" class="dropdown-item">
      {% if lang_code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% else %}
        <i class="bi bi-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% endif %}
      {{ lang_name }} ({{ lang_code }})
    </a>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</li>
```

Other parts of code remains basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would add some improvements to the previous answers:

1. Translate the url before the redirection
2. Ensure to read the "next" param when present
3. Disable the set_language redirect view

About points 1 and 2, here an improved implementation of the `ActivateLanguageView`, directly inspired by the `django.views.i18n.set_language` official Django function (that unfortunately is a POST)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import translate_url
from django.utils.translation import check_for_language
from django.views.generic import View


class ActivateLanguageView(View):

    def get(self, request, language_code, **kwargs):
        next_url = self.request.GET.get("next", self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(next_url) if next_url else HttpResponse(status=404)
        if check_for_language(language_code):
            if next_url:
                next_trans = translate_url(next_url, language_code)
                if next_trans != next_url:
                    response = HttpResponseRedirect(next_trans)
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language_code)
        return response
```

About point 3, the `@Boris Đurkan` and `@jlandercy`'s answers about the url and template files are valid, but I'd explicitly remove the following if included in your urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    # path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),  # REMOVE ME!
]
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) more details about the set_language redirect view from the official Django docs.